# Which field does $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ refer to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, notation

I'm reading a textbook on algebraic geometry and it mentions the field  $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ without defining it. It does define $\mathbb{C}(t)$ as the field of rational functions with coefficients in the complex numbers.

Comment: algebraic closure of $\overline{\Bbb C(t)}$

Comment: I meant of $\mathbb C(t)$

Comment: If you can an exact block quote where this appears would be super helpful; also, the title and author(s) of said book

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series you can represent $f \in \overline{\Bbb{C}(t)}$ as a Laurent series in $t^{1/n}$ convergent for $0< |t| < r$ small. Its conjugates are then obtained by continuing $f$ analytically along closed curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ is the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of ${\mathbb{C}(t)}$.

For example, $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)} $ contains an element $\tau$ such that $\tau^2-t=0,$ 
 though $\mathbb C(t)$ does not.

Comment: Is there a one line description of the functions in $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$? For example the functions in $\mathbb{C}(t)$ are fractions with polynomials as numerator and denominator.

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$ has all the roots of polynomials in $\Bbb C(t)$, so it includes roots such as $t^{1/2}$, as well as other algebraic expressions involving such